# Complete a positive definite correlation matrix

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, correlation

I want to *complete* a correlation matrix so that it becomes positive definite, where I only care about the correlations of each variable with the first variable, and the rest can be anything. So for example, I'd like to *complete* this correlation matrix, filling in the `--`'s to any set of numbers so that the matrix becomes positive definite.

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,] 1.00 0.76 0.77 0.78 0.79 0.81 0.82 0.83 0.84
 [2,] 0.76 1.00  --   --   --   --   --   --   -- 
 [3,] 0.77  --  1.00  --   --   --   --   --   -- 
 [4,] 0.78  --   --  1.00  --   --   --   --   -- 
 [5,] 0.79  --   --   --  1.00  --   --   --   -- 
 [6,] 0.81  --   --   --   --  1.00  --   --   -- 
 [7,] 0.82  --   --   --   --   --  1.00  --   -- 
 [8,] 0.83  --   --   --   --   --   --  1.00  -- 
 [9,] 0.84  --   --   --   --   --   --   --  1.00
```

There's functions like [nearcor](https://rdrr.io/cran/sfsmisc/man/nearcor.html) for "fixing" positive definite correlation matrices, but they optimize for all the variables, instead of filling in some, while respecting others. Or there's functions like [pos_def_limits](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/faux/versions/1.2.0/topics/pos_def_limits) for while-looping to fill in a single next correlation value, but it seems intractable to do this for many values at the same time.

(The intended usage of this correlation matrix, is to give it to [rnorm_multi](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/faux/versions/1.2.0/topics/rnorm_multi) to generate data satisfying it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can start constructing a positive definite matrix `M` from a lower-triangular matrix `L` with positive diagonal entries, e.g., `M = L*L^T`, such that `x^T*M*x = x^T*L*L^T*x = |L^T*x|^2` should be definitely positive if `x>0`.

An implementation for example:

```
n <- 9
L <- diag(n)
L[-1, 1] <- c(76:79, 81:84) / 100
v <- 1 - L[, 1]^2
for (k in 2:length(v)) {
  L[k, 2:k] <- sqrt((r <- runif(k - 1)) / sum(r) * v[k])
}
M <- tcrossprod(L)
```

and we can see

```
> M
      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]
 [1,] 1.00 0.7600000 0.7700000 0.7800000 0.7900000 0.8100000 0.8200000
 [2,] 0.76 1.0000000 0.8883572 0.7988221 0.7328434 0.7003986 0.7966054
 [3,] 0.77 0.8883572 1.0000000 0.8972778 0.7937081 0.8500339 0.8200438
 [4,] 0.78 0.7988221 0.8972778 1.0000000 0.9093460 0.8651427 0.8668928
 [5,] 0.79 0.7328434 0.7937081 0.9093460 1.0000000 0.8581035 0.9336535
 [6,] 0.81 0.7003986 0.8500339 0.8651427 0.8581035 1.0000000 0.9105348
 [7,] 0.82 0.7966054 0.8200438 0.8668928 0.9336535 0.9105348 1.0000000
 [8,] 0.83 0.6964236 0.7789939 0.7994304 0.8621129 0.9136291 0.9507678
 [9,] 0.84 0.7344271 0.8091267 0.7860827 0.8387232 0.9097534 0.9200662
           [,8]      [,9]
 [1,] 0.8300000 0.8400000
 [2,] 0.6964236 0.7344271
 [3,] 0.7789939 0.8091267
 [4,] 0.7994304 0.7860827
 [5,] 0.8621129 0.8387232
 [6,] 0.9136291 0.9097534
 [7,] 0.9507678 0.9200662
 [8,] 1.0000000 0.9652907
 [9,] 0.9652907 1.0000000
```

and we can check that all eigen values are greater than `0`

```
> all(eigen(M)$values > 0)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks! This does exactly what I was looking for :) I'll have to spend some time understanding how the maths of it works though.. :P

(For anyone looking into this later: when using the `rnorm_multi` function, you need to set the `empirical = TRUE` flag to get data of which the correlation matrix is indeed exactly the one you started with.)

Answer (score 3):

There may be some piece of elegant linear algebra that works, but brute force seems OK for this problem.

```r
## set up matrix with required form
m <- matrix(NA, 9, 9)
diag(m) <- 1
m[1,-1] <- m[-1, 1] <- c(76:79, 81:84)/100

mk_matrix <- function(p) {
    ## fill in lower triangle
    m[col(m) > 1 & row(m) > col(m)] <- p
    ## symmetrize
    m[upper.tri(m)] <- t(m)[upper.tri(m)]
    m
}

objfun <- function(p = rnorm(8*7/2)) {
    r <- -1*det(mk_matrix(p))
    ## cat(r, "\n")
    r
}
```

Positive values of `objfun` denote negative-definite matrices.

It seems we have about a 50/50 chance of getting a pos-def matrix by filling in random Normal values:

```r
set.seed(101)
rr <- replicate(1000, objfun())
hist(rr, breaks = 50)
```

[image]

In any case, we could use `optim()` with `abstol` to stop as soon as we get a negative value (== a pos def result)

```r
set.seed(104) ## chosen to get a neg def starting matrix
optim(par = rnorm(8*7/2), 
      fn = objfun, control=list(abstol = 1e-8))
```

Comment: Very interesting approach with `optim`, +1!

Answer (score 1):

If you truly don't care about the other correlations, you can pull samples directly in linear time. (You can apply point-wise linear transformations to the result without changing the correlations.)

```
correlations <- c(1, 0.76, 0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.84)
n <- length(correlations)
samples <- correlations * rnorm(1) + sqrt(1 - correlations^2) * rnorm(n)
```